# Finding the kth smallest element in an unsorted array

Tags: java, sorting, partitioning, pseudocode

I'm trying to implement the following pseudocode. I need to do this using logical partitions only.

```
Procedure SELECT( k,S) 
{ if  |S| =1 then return the single element in S
   else  { choose an element a randomly from S;
          let S1,S2,and S3 be he sequences of elements in S   
          less than, equal to, and greater than m, respectively;
         if |S1| >=k then return SELECT(k,S1)
          else 
               if (|S1| + |S2| >=k then return m
               else  return SELECT(k-|S1|-|S2| , S3);
         }
}
```

Here is my attempt at it so far:

```
public static int select(int k, int[] s, int arrayLeft, int arrayRight) {
    if (s.length == 1) {
        return s[0];
    } else {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int right = rand.nextInt(arrayRight) + arrayLeft;
        int m = s[right];
        int pivot = partition(s, arrayLeft, right); // pivot = |s1|
        if (pivot >= k) {
            return select(k, s, arrayLeft, pivot - 1);
        } else {
            // Calculate |s2|
            int s2Length = 0;
            for (int i = pivot; s[i] == m; i++) {
                s2Length++;
            }
            if (pivot + s2Length >= k) {
                return m;
            } else {
                int s3Left = pivot + s2Length;
                return select(k - pivot - s2Length, s, s3Left + 1, s.length);
            }
        }
    }
}

// all elements smaller than m are to the left of it,
// all elements greater than m are to the right of it
private static int partition(int[] s, int left, int right) {
    int m = s[right];
    int i = left;
    for (int j = left; j <= right - 1; j++) {
        if (s[j] <= m) {
            swap(s, i, j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(s, i, right);
    return i;
}

private static void swap(int[] s, int i, int j) {
    int temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = temp;
}
```

My `select` method isn't returning the actual kth smallest element. The partition method only does its job properly on the elements smaller than m. On the portion of the array to the right of m, there are elements of any value. How do I fix this? All of the solutions I've seen online appear the same as my method. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused. Where in the pseudo code does it say anything about reordering the array? Because if you're gonna reorder anyway, you can just use a sort algorithm and return the kth element of the array afterwards...

Comment: The algorithm is supposed to be faster than a complete sort. You’ve got to represent S1, S2 and S3 somehow, doing it by reordering the array is not the silliest thing to do.

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Is `select` supposed to select the kth smallest element among array indices `arrayLeft` through `arrayRight` inclusive? Exclusive?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear with this. When the user first calls the method, arrayLeft is 0 and arrayRight is the last element in the array. I should make another method to call `select` so that the user only needs to specify k and the array.

Comment: Ole V.V., is there a better way that you know of to do this that doesn't involve reordering the array?

Comment: When I programmed the same problem a couple of years ago, I certainly reordered the array. If you wanted your Java code to reflect your pseudocode more directly, you might distribute the elements into three new arrays or `ArrayLists`s `s1`, `s2` and `s3` rather than reordering the existing array; it wouldn’t be the conventional way of solving it; might be clearer?

Comment: I wish I could, but this is for an assignment and I'm not allowed to create any new arrays.

Comment: In that case I see no good way around reordering within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the details of how your code was supposed to work, but I think I have spotted a few suspicious points.

First I think you should be precise about the valid arguments for you method and how it uses `arrayLeft` and `arrayRight`. Write a Javadoc comment and state this. It will make it much easier for yourself and anyone else to argue about what is correct and incorrect in the code.

This is wrong:

```
    if (s.length == 1) {
```

You are passing the same array through all your recursive calls, so if it didn’t have length 1 from the outset (a trivial case), it will never have length 1. Instead use `arrayLeft` and `arrayRight` to determine the number of elements to consider.

This line does not look right:

```
        int right = rand.nextInt(arrayRight) + arrayLeft;
```

If `arrayLeft` is 10 and `arrayRight` 12, it may yield up to 21. I did observe an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the following line once because `right` pointed outside the array.

The comment in this line is incorrect and may lead you to wrong arguments about the code:

```
        int pivot = partition(s, arrayLeft, right); // pivot = |s1|
```

The `pivot` returned from `partition()` is the index to `m` after reordering. I think the correct statement is `pivot == arrayLeft + |s1|`. Please check yourself.

I further believe that you should not pass `right` as the last argument in the above call, but `arrayRight`. This error may be the cause for your observation that `partition()` leaves any values to the right of `m`.

You may risk an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` here too:

```
            for (int i = pivot; s[i] == m; i++) {
```

You should add an additional condition like `i <= arrayRight` or `i < s.length`.

Finally, this looks wrong in my eyes:

```
                return select(k - pivot - s2Length, s, s3Left + 1, s.length);
```

I am thinking:

```
                return select(k - pivot - s2Length, s, s3Left, arrayRight);
```

But please check with your own knowledge. I am particularly in doubt about `arrayRight`.